# data.table::setorder on data.frame input order only the sort column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm passing a `data.frame` to a function that sort it using `data.table::setorder`. Before sorting, I'm calling `data.table::setDT` on the input (in actuality I need to later call some specific `data.table` functions on the input). This is the function I'm using:

```
test_order <- function(x) {
  data.table::setDT(x)
  data.table::setorder(x, score)
}
```

and this is how I'm calling it:

```
x0 <- data.frame(id = 1:3, score = c(20, 10, 30))
x1 <- test_order(x0)
```

The results seem strange:

- The type of `x0` is changed to a `data.table` - that seems okay;
- The column `x0$id` is **not modified** - it's address (using `data.table::address`) remains the same, and it also remains in the original order;
- The column `x0$score` also remains at the same address, but it is now **sorted**, so it's out of sync with the `id` column;
- The resulting `x1` has the rows sorted correctly; also, the `score` column is at the same address as the `score` column of `x0`, but the `id` column is, of course, at a different address.
  Here is what I get:

```
> x0
  id score
1  1    20
2  2    10
3  3    30
> x1 <- test_order(x0)
> x0
   id score
1:  1    10
2:  2    20
3:  3    30
> x1
   id score
1:  2    10
2:  1    20
3:  3    30
```

The most "surprising" thing is the loss of data integrity of the `x0` object - the `id` column keeps the original order but the `score` column got sorted, so the rows are different from the rows of the original object.
This does not happen if I'm not calling `setDT` or if I'm passing a `data.table` object instead of a `data.frame`.

The version of the `data.table` package is 1.14.2

Comment: Interesting. I'd expect `x0` and `x1` to be identical (as `setDT` like all `set*` should do it's job by reference).  A quick fix (although less optimal) would be to add `x <- data.table::copy(x)` at the start of your function.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver. I'm aware that I can use `copy`, but I was expecting the same as you - that the two datasets would be the same. And more over, even if they wouldn't be the same (say the original dataset would not be sorted at all), the fact that only one of the columns of the original data is sorted is puzzling, and seems incorrect.

Comment: This seems like a bug, I suggest you submit this as a [new issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=issue_template.md). This is a well-framed test-set, too, very straight-forward, easy to test and confirm.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, I submitted an issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5379

Comment: TLDR: Call `setDT(x0)` at the top level. Don't expect `setDT` to "bubble up" through environments.  R as a language does not have reference semantics.  `setDT(x)` reassigns a new object to the name "x". The only guarantee is that name `x` in `test_order` will be replaced with a data.table.  AFAICT, any changes to `x0` are undefined behavior. R uses "lazy copying", by letting copies point to the same components (columns, attributes) as the original until they're modified *in R*.  Because `data.table` modifies columns and attributes in C, you're forcing R to break some promises around copying.